# How to rotate a plotted igraph, given a specific layout (r code)?

Tags: r, plot, rotation, igraph

I have the following code:

```
require(igraph)
g = make_star(8, mode="undirected", center=1)
layout.old = layout_with_fr(g, dim=3)
plot(g, layout = layout.old)
```

I'd like to plot the same graph but with a rotation of degree *a* for any *a* w.r.t. the original layout, w.r.t. a fixed axis, no matter what it is. The idea is to construct a step-wise animation, so I need to plot a new graph (using the function 'plot') for each step (each step gives the same graph, but rotated).

How to do that?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the `rgl::rotate3d` function.  For example to rotate
by 10, 20, ..., 100 degrees about the axis in direction `(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)` use

```
for (a in 10*(1:10)) {
   plot(g, layout = rgl::rotate3d(layout.old, a*pi/180, x=1,y=1,z=1))
   Sys.sleep(1)
}
```

You could also use `rglplot(g, layout = layout.old)` for an interactive plot.

Comment: Thanks, I unfortunately obtain the error

Error in rotate3d.default(layout.old, a * pi/180, x = 1, y = 1, z = 1) : 
  Unsupported object for rotation

How would you fix it?

Comment: I don't get any error when I run your code followed by mine, so I've got no idea what went wrong for you.

Comment: Maybe you didn't use `dim = 3`?